# Change MapView Polyline style dynamically when user start moving on route in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3, mapkit

I am using Apple MapView to show navigation in my app. I am able to change the style of Polyline to dashed pattern from pickup location to destination location with the help of following code:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
    renderer.strokeColor = POLYLINE_COLOR
    renderer.lineWidth = 3
    renderer.lineDashPattern =[0,6]
    return renderer
}
```

I want to change the dash pattern polyline to straight line as user move towards the destination location. Suppose User is moving towards Destination, then PickUp to User polyline should be straight line, and User to Destination should be Dash line.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is keeping a reference to the created `MKPolylineRenderer` object.

Then, if something happens (like a moving user), I update renderer, for example a new lineDashPattern.

Then I call `renderer.setNeedsDisplay()`

That's it.

Remember to do all updates to the renderer object and `renderer.setNeedsDisplay()` in the main Queue.